# How to trim Characters in Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, string

I am getting http response as an array from php in android. The response i sent is a  ULR. When i get it, it comes as:

```
["http:\/\/karan.development.com\/Image_android\/upload_image_14552.jpg"]
```

I tried to remove the charachters as:

```
String trim;
trim = beforeTrim.replaceAll("[\]", "");
```

here, "beforeTrim" is a string where the url is stored.
But unfortunately it dosen't works. Please anyone help

Comment: How are you receiving your input? The string you've supplied appears to be JSON-encoded. If you deserialize your response using GSON or some other JSON deserializer, I would expect the escape characters to disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hy karan, you just have to do this for special characters:

```
String trim;
String trim = beforeTrim.replaceAll("[|?*<\">+\\[\\]/']", "");
System.out.println("After trimming"+" " +trim);
```

The result you will get is:

```
http://karan.development.com/Image_android/upload_image_14552.jpg
```

Hope this will help !

Comment: That regular expression seems way too complicated for the task at hand.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you just need to escape the regex escape sequence (which is `\`):

```
trim = beforeTrim.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
System.out.println(trim);
```

that prints:

```
http://karan.development.com/Image_android/upload_image_14552.jpg
```

The reason for 4 `\` characters is:

- regex needs two `\\` to escape `\` and make it a `\` character
- java String literals need two `\\` to escape `\` and make it a `\` character